# Automate launching Java app (instead of entering command)

Tags: java, automation

I've downloaded the Java RESTClient tool, which is a Swing-based GUI app. Unfortunately, there is no .exe to launch like with other apps (at least those I've written in .NET).

Instead, I have to launch this command every time:

```
java -jar restclient-2.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Is there a way in which I can automate launching this command?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which environment you are in.  The automation varies accordingly.

- For graphic environments create a new application launcher.  You will need to set the desired directory and specify the command to use.
- For command line environments put a script in on your path that runs the command.

Answer (score 1):

Put the command in a file named restclient.bat.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a windows environment with a normal Java installation, you should be able to just create a shortcut to your `restclient-2.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar` file, and let the shell association for .jar handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use java webstart, look up the jnlp syntax. Its great if you want to launch from a web page for instance.